# Countdown timer in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to make a countdown timer using VBA in excel that uses a message box and counts down in increments of 5 from 200.
Any thoughts on how I can do this?
So far I have the following but i can't figure out how to count down in 5:

```
Public Sub ShowCountDown()
    Dim Timerbox As Object: Set Timerbox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim strCnt As String

    For i = 0 To 199
        strCnt = 200 - (4 + i)
        Timerbox.Popup strCnt, 1, "CountDown", vbOKOnly
    Next i

    MsgBox "Time is up", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Comment: Plenty of thoughts. But we're not going to write code for you. What have you already tried? Also - have you see the "related" questions here on SO? The methods already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code counts from 196 to -3 in single steps.

> i can't figure out how to count down in 5

You can use the `Step` clause in the `For` statement:

```
For i = 200 To 0 Step -5
    Timerbox.Popup i, 1, "CountDown", vbOKOnly
Next i
```